# Taboo.vim to show basename of the current file

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

When I'm programming. My structure is based on a simple tree.

```
.
├── index.js
└── Pages
    ├── blog
    │   └── index.js
    ├── career
    ├── contacts
    │   └── index.js
    ├── dashboard
    ├── home
    │   └── index.js
    ├── Layouts
    ├── Menus
    └── portfolio
        └── index.js

9 directories, 5 files
```

A tree from my actual project.

Whenever I need a feature I make a directory for it and when I create a file inside vim I need to always

```
TabooRename %basename%
```

of the file so in `portfolio/index.js` file's tab is read "Portfolio" and all files follow this convention.

I need to somehow allow this feature in my Taboo settings so I won't have to set it every time.

Looking at their example in setting it's naming convention [here](https://github.com/gcmt/taboo.vim#basic-options) I couldn't find a perfect fit for me.

I tried

```
let g:taboo_tab_format="%p%m"
```

But this set my tabs to a very long path from the root of my system. But I only need from the basename of the current file I'm editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc you linked `%p` (lower case pee) displays the  tab's current working directory which may be a full path. `%P` (*upper case* pee) displays only the last component of that directory (it's "tail"). For directory `/foo/bar/baz` that would show just `baz`.

Note that when you open a new file/buffer Vim won't by default change the current working directory to the location of that file. If you want that add `set autochdir` in your vimrc. (FYI, the help for this option says "Note: When this option is on some plugins may not work.")